# Sending more Email Campaigns (with Templates) from ISV Package

Tags: managed-package, email-template, governorlimits, isv, campaign

I have a `Managed Package` in the AppExchange that now should make extensive use of `Standard Email Campaigns` to engage with customers. We don't want to use a complex and heavy extension like Pardot but now struggle to envision how to overcome the Email limits of

1. **5000 per day** - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381534&type=1

> "Each licensed Salesforce org can send single emails to a maximum of 5,000 external email addresses..."

2. **1000 per day** - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382442&type=1

> "The daily limit for emails sent from workflow and approval-related email alerts is 1,000 per standard Salesforce license per organization.

I am quite we wont stay in the first limit and if we can leverage the second one. So my question is what is the

best approach or recommended tools first an ISV that wants to

1. Don't build a custom Email solution but use Email Campaign and Templates
2. Doesn't want to have users use AppExchange Apps like MailChimp
3. Needs something which is packagable and doesn't need additional licences

Maybe a pure API solution where we provide connectivity as a Post Install Step?

Comment: I am reading `1,000 per standard Salesforce license per organization. The overall organization limit is 2,000,000` for the second limit. So 1000 emails per license/user per day. That scales quite well imho
For the 5000 daily limit, I have seen queues being built. send 4000, save 1000 for own use, send rest over the next day(s)

Comment: Szandor: right but I was more concerned about "workflow and approval-related" do I need to use a deprecated workflow or a fake approval to send those emails?

Comment: That's a tricky requirement considering item #2. What are you thinking about orgs that hit the platform's limits? And regarding the limits themselves: I'm fairly sure those are the kind of thing you can pay for more limits (highly recommend to check with an AE though).

Comment: Robert: I understand this as meaning "email alert" as using and email action under the hood as opposed to Single Email Message. Flow uses Actions as well, only recently introduced Single Email Message capabilities.  
Having you considered macros? emails sent from ui to crm objects don't end up eating limits. cf https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386730&type=1

Comment: The #1 consideration and why customers use Pardot or Marketing Cloud with SAP or 3rd party services such as MailChimp is deliverability. In a non-ISV scenario when sending email from a core cloud, you could implement DMARC/DKIM/SPF to help. Not sure how this works with ISV and AppExchange.

Comment: @identigral DMARC/DKIM/SPF?!

Comment: @RobertSösemann https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389240&type=1